# angular intro.js not available

Tags: angularjs, intro.js

I have been trying to use angular intro js in my mockup angular js project the modal that asks whether the user needs to go through the tutorial is visible, However when I click the ok button that invokes the callMe method , an error is printed in the console stating,

> message:"Intro.js is not available. Make sure it is properly loaded."
>   name:"Introjs not available."

Could anyone suggest where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have refered the angular-intro library and also injected as a dependency.

**Reference:**

```
 <script src="intro.min.js"></script>
 <script src="angular-intro.js"></script>
 <script src="app.js"></script>
```

**Module:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular-intro']);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/YHcuf5jdIkbSfjECDmzq?p=preview)**

Comment: yes I have refered the angular-intro library and also injected it as a dependency but I get this error

Comment: provided solution is correct I think something is wrong with your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Sajeetharan's comment: It turns out that the order of dependency MATTERS. You must include the intro.js first, then angular-intro.js, then the main app.js.

Otherwise, you might get

> Intro.js is not available. Make sure it is properly loaded." name:"Introjs not available.